# Indices upon a table which has undergone multi-column partitioning

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning, database-indexes

Consider the following table (contrived example):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users_per_service` (
  `host` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `port` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_num` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY KEY(host, port)
```

We've partitioned this by `(host, port)`. My understanding is that a physical table will be made for each distinct `(host, port)` tuple.

The kind of data you might see are:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE `users_per_service`
(host, port, user_num, user_name)
VALUES
('localhost', 8080, 0, 'tom'),
('localhost', 8080, 1, 'jerry'),
('example.com', 8080, 0, 'barry')
('example.com', 8081, 0, 'jeff');
```

Let's say that I am only interested in the partition `('localhost', 8080)`.
I want a list of all its users, ordered by `user_num`.

Obviously this will work:

```sql
CREATE INDEX service_users_by_num ON users_per_service(host, port, user_num);

SELECT *
FROM users_per_service
WHERE host = 'localhost'
AND port = 8080
ORDER BY host, port, user_num
```

But do I really need the three-column index? I already *partitioned* by `(host, port)`.

So let's try and simplify.

**Will the following `ORDER BY` use the `service_users_by_num` index?**

```sql
CREATE INDEX service_users_by_num ON users_per_service(host, port, user_num);

SELECT *
FROM users_per_service
WHERE host = 'localhost'
AND port = 8080
ORDER BY user_num
```

Multi-column indices cannot *usually* be used like this. But with partitions, a vital clue is available: `WHERE (host, port)` ensures we are in a table with only one possible value for host or port. This *could* mean that the index `(host, port, user_num)` is equivalent to an index on just `(user_num)`.

We may be able to go simpler:

```sql
CREATE INDEX service_users_by_num ON users_per_service(user_num);

SELECT *
FROM users_per_service
WHERE host = 'localhost'
AND port = 8080
ORDER BY user_num
```

**Would this query give me *just* the contents of selected partition `('localhost', 8080)`, sorted by `user_num`?** (i.e. filter first, *then* sort the results — as opposed to the other way around).

Overall: I'm trying to understand how multi-column partitioning interacts with multi-column indices.